# How can we pass dynamic arguments in [Arguments] tag for BenchmarkDotNet in C#?

Tags: c#, performance-testing, benchmarkdotnet

I am trying to benchmark a method with parameters.

```
[Benchmark]
public void ViewPlan(int x)
{
//code here
}
```

While executing the code with [Benchmark] annotation, I got an error as 
"Benchmark method ViewPlan has incorrect signature. Method shouldn't have any arguments".
So I tried to add [Arguments] annotation to the method as well.
Refer link: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/samples/IntroArguments.html

```
[Benchmark]
[Arguments]
public void ViewPlan(int x)
{
//code here
}
```

In this [Arguments] we need to specify the value of the parameter for the method as well. However, value of x is set dynamically when the functionality is called.
Is there any way to pass the parameter value dynamically in [Arguments] ?
Also can we benchmark static methods?If yes then how?

Comment: You can use `ArgumentsSource` as mentioned [here](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/features/parameterization.html) and you can generate random numbers in there.

Comment: @Eldar the value of x can be anything. There is a grid which has for eg 1000 records. So x contains the rownumber on which user has clicked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have made an example for you. See if it fits your needs.

```
public class IntroSetupCleanupIteration
{
        private int rowCount;
        private IEnumrable<object> innerSource;

        public IEnumerable<object> Source => this.innerSource; 

        [IterationSetup]
        public void IterationSetup()
        {
             // retrieve data or setup your grid row count for each iteration
             this.InitSource(42);
        }

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void GlobalSetup()
        {
             // retrieve data or setup your grid row count for every iteration
             this.InitSource(42);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Source))]
        public void ViewPlan(int x)
        {
            // code here
        }

        private void InitSource(int rowCount)
        {
            this.innerSource = Enumerable.Range(0,rowCount).Select(t=> (object)t).ToArray(); // you can also shuffle it
        }
}
```

I don't know how you set up your data. For each iteration or once for every iteration so i include both setups.

Comment: This solution seems a bit contrived just to pass a value without changing your source code. In 2024 have you found a better way since then?

Comment: @Urasquirrel I don't know what you are trying to say. It is a sample to demonstrate how to pass dynamic data to a benchmark, where the dynamic part can be read from a csv file, a database, a web service, etc.

Comment: Yes as you say it is an example. I was asking have you found a better way since this original post? I ended up following this example and was able to make it work, however I dislike how we have to muddle the class with additional methods and properties. In a situation where we are dealing with enterprise code, this just seems like a lot to deal with. I have since found MethodTimer.Fody which requires doing nothing but an attribute, but it only offers trace timestamps of live runs which isn't really what I was looking for, but does get me part of the way there with less garbage added to a class

Comment: @Urasquirrel Yes they have kept the same structure intact but since they didn't release the 1.0 yet there is a small chance of change. Since the arguments are configured over attributes and attributes require compile time constants it is not likely to provide an alternate syntax unless you move the arguments configuration somewhere else, maybe a generic configuration class would be a cleaner approach.

Comment: I love that option. Thanks for the reply! @Eldar